# QTP unable to read external excel file when executed, using vb script

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to run test on QTP using vb script, I am able to open QTP and start running the test.  But, the test is unable to access the external data sheet which is required to fetch data from.

**This is the code:**

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Dim qtpAppObj,qtpTest

'Create the QTP Application object
Set qtpAppObj = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") 

'Open the test in read-only mode
qtpAppObj.Open c:\test, True  

'set run settings for the test
Set qtpTest = qtpAppObj.Test
```